# Excel: Comparar valores en distintos formatos

Tags: excel

He creado la siguiente fórmula para determinar mi jornada horaria:

```
=SI(O(MES(HOY()) = 7; MES(HOY()) = 8); "7:00"; SI(DIASEM(HOY(); 2) = 5; "6:00"; "8:45"))
```

Quiero establecer una comparación con otra celda que me devuelve las horas trabajadas para un día cualquiera, de manera que si no se llega al mínimo que establece la fórmula, la celda se coloree en color rojo.

La celda en cuestión, `D12`, suma el tiempo empleado en las diferentes tareas, `=SUMA(D2:D11)`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todas las celdas que no incluyen texto tienen el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las columnas "Inicio" y "Fin" representan la hora de inicio y fin de cada tarea, y "Duración" la duración en horas de la tarea, tal que `=B2-A2`, y así sucesivamente para el resto de tareas.

El problema, creo, es que Excel no reconoce como equivalentes el formato del valor de `F12` y el del que devuelve la fórmula condicional, por lo que el color, aplicado mediante la opción de "Formato condicional", no funciona correctamente.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel no reconoce la equivalencia entre la celda D2 con el resultado de la fórmula que determina tu jornada diaria porque la primera la lee como un número y la segunda como un texto. En este caso, puedes utilizar la función HORANUMERO() para convertir el texto en un número decimal.

Sabiendo esto, ya puedes aplicar el color:

Formato Condicional > Nueva Regla > "Utilice una fórmula que determine las celdas para aplicar formato". Allí digitas la fórmula que creaste, pero tomando en cuenta la conversión de texto a número que debes realizar:

```
=$D$12<HORANUMERO(SI(O(MES(HOY()) = 7; MES(HOY()) = 8); "7:00"; SI(DIASEM(HOY(); 2) = 5; "6:00"; "8:45")))
```

Eliges el formato con el color de tu preferencia, le das clic en "Aceptar" y la celda D2 ya debería tomar el color que elegiste para valores menores al indicado por la fórmula de tu jornada diaria.